# Call JavaScript function in opener

Tags: javascript

I need to to trigger a JavaScript function in an opener window by clicking a button in the child.

I thought the following would work, but it is not.

```
window.opener.MyFunction()
```

Comment: That should work.  When you say that it is not, can you give more information?

Comment: Is your `MyFunction` attached to the opener window?

Comment: The function is declared in the opener window.  Even if I change the function to close(), it does not work.  Could using Google Chrome be part of the problem?

Comment: What browsers have you tried this in?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that MyFunction() was inside a jQuery document.ready statement.  It worked fine after I changed that.  Interesting though, window.opener.close() still does not work.

Comment: You should accept your own answer, there's a badge for that. ;)  And I believe Chrome (and other browsers) specifically will not let you close windows that were not opened by a script.

Answer (score 0):

Are both windows on the same domain (e.g. foo.com?) It might be blocked due to reasons of cross-site scripting security.

Comment: Sam domain.  In fact they are both included in the same file with a GET Variable used to distinguish

Answer (score 0):

It works for me on IE9.  I need to open separate window for a user to upload a doc and on successful upload I must tell opener window to perform some task.  Might be other browser you mentioned does not support this.

Answer (score -1):

Try using :

window.onload = function()
{
   MyFunction();
}